# Comma as decimal separator space as thousand separator C#

Tags: c#, decimal, string-formatting

I want to show my decimal type numbers in my WPF DataGrid using **comma** as **decimal** and **space** as **thousand** separator, with the decimals **length of 4 max**.

I'm really confused by this **StringFormat** property, I can't seem to find the meaning of the string I have to specify.

Example:

```
1234567890.987654 --> 1 234 567 890,988
```

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

The second main part of this question is how to do this in **WPF Datagrid**, I'll post here, how to change a column's binding from code:

```
        (stockDataGrid.Columns[1] as DataGridTextColumn).Binding = new Binding("Amount") { ConverterCulture = culture, StringFormat = "c" };
```

Comment: you should post how you try to 'stringify' number. Are you applying culture? or specific format in ToString() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify both format string and format info:

```
  decimal source = 1234567890.987654m;

  string result = source.ToString(
    "###,###,###,###.###", 
     new NumberFormatInfo() {
       NumberGroupSeparator = " ",
       NumberDecimalSeparator = ","});
```

If it's too complex and you have to format many currencies in such a way, you can modify the culture:

```
  CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;

  culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = " ";
  culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
  culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "";
  culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 3;
  culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSizes = new int[] {3};

  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;

  ...

  decimal source = 1234567890.987654m;

  string result = source.ToString("c");
```